# Prevent browser's back button to go on after logout

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

i am using laravel 5.8.After logout if i press back button then previous page occurs.And the problem is that on that page things are going as usual.In short no it gives no benefit of using logging out functionality. Whats the solution.Can anyone tell?

Comment: Are you sure the session is deleted?

Comment: Yes. I forget the session.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you have yet to define any middleware to ensure only authenticated users have access to view the page.

1) You can put in your route file:

```
Route::get('profile', 'UserController@show')->middleware('auth');
```

2) Or, you can put it in the function '__construct' within the controller :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

If you want to limit the middleware to only certain method(s):

```
$this->middleware('log')->only('index');
```

If you want to exclude certain method(s):

```
$this->middleware('subscribed')->except('store');
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#controller-middleware

Comment: No it's not working. As I already included a middleware to check session is null or not on that route but still this logical error occurs.

Comment: As u can see this is the middleware. It works properly before and after login but not works when browser back button is pressed after logout.

Comment: `public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->session()->get('name')===null){
            return redirect('/admin_log');
        }
        
        return $next($request);
    }`